# dplyr: group_by, sum various columns, and apply a function based on grouped row sums?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I'm trying to use dplyr to summarize a dataframe of bird species abundance in forests which are fragmented to some degree.

The first column, percent_cover, has 4 possible values: 10, 25, 50, 75. Then there are ten columns of bird species counts: 'species1' through 'species10'.

I want to group by percent_cover, then sum the other columns and calculate these sums as a percentage of the 4 row sums.

To get to the column sums is easy enough:

---

```
%>% group_by(Percent_cover) %>% summarise_at(vars(contains("species")), sum)
```

---

...but what I need is sum/rowSum*100. It seems that some kind of 'rowwise' operation is needed.

Also, out of interest, why does the following not work?

---

```
%>% group_by(Percent_cover) %>% summarise_at(vars(contains("species")), sum*100)
```

---

At this point, it's tempting to go back to 'for' loops....or Excel pivot tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `dplyr`, try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Percent_cover) %>% 
  summarise(across(contains("species"), sum)) %>%
  mutate(rs = rowSums(select(., contains("species")))) %>%
  mutate(across(contains('species'), ~./rs * 100)) -> result

result
```

For example, using `mtcars` :

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(across(disp:wt, sum)) %>%
  mutate(rs = rowSums(select(., disp:wt))) %>%
  mutate(across(disp:wt, ~./rs * 100))

#   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt    rs
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4  54.2  42.6 2.10  1.18  2135.
#2     6  58.7  39.2 1.15  0.998 2186.
#3     8  62.0  36.7 0.567 0.702 7974.
```

Comment: Very nice Ronak. Worth adding a `.names = "{col}_percent"` to your final `across` for clarity?

Comment: That's a good suggestion for clarity. However, it would keep the original columns as it is and create a new column with those new names.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if `across` had an option to overwrite the original columns without having to keep their names the same.